# How to dynamically populate the drop down list with checkbox and submit in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp, jdbc

I have already fetched the data from database and again I have to fetch in same table & same corresponding id where referencedComponentId =? . For this,if I click the button it show dynamically drop down with check box and I have to select one check box and submit . After submit it again fetch one row from table. Below code will fetch data from table and I struck how to populate drop down with check box and submit and this is my code below

## code

```
<%!public class Code {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/snomedtoicd10";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";

        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        public Code() {

            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,
                        password);
                String sql = "select * from snomedcsvotherwise where referencedComponentId=? ";
                pstm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
           // AND `mapRule` LIKE '%TRUE%'
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public ResultSet getCode(String Snomedcode) {

            try {
                pstm.setString(1, Snomedcode);
                resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultSet;
        }
    }%>

    <%
        String snomedcode = new String();

        String str = request.getParameter("snomedcode");
        if (str != null) {
            snomedcode = str;
        }
        Code c = new Code();
        ResultSet codes = c.getCode(snomedcode);    
    %>

    <h2 align="center">
        <font><strong>SNOMED CODE TO ICD 10 CODE</strong></font>
    </h2>

    <div style='min-height:40px'>
    <table id="tblMain" width="100%" class='table1' border=0 cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='topmargin:-5px'>

    <tr class='headerText' style='height:25px'>
        <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 10%'>SNOMED</td>
        <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 40%'>SNOMED Name</td>
        <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 10%'>ICD-10</td>
        <td class='tdcellblue' style='width: 40%'>ICD Name</td>
    </tr>
        <%
            while (codes.next()) {
                String maprule = null;
                maprule=(codes.getString("mapRule"));
                if(maprule.matches("OTHERWISE TRUE") || maprule.matches("TRUE"))
                {
        %>

        <tr >
            <td><%=codes.getString("referencedComponentId")%></td>
            <td><%=codes.getString("sctName")%></td>
            <td><%=codes.getString("mapTarget")%></td>
            <td><%=codes.getString("icdName")%></td>
        </tr>

    <%}%>

    <%}%>
```

Comment: Populate dropdown when the user selects a checkbox?

Comment: no ! after clicking a button it need to dropdown and dropdown contains check box @Perdomoff